# How to use Near tool then join by FID to calculate exposure index

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, fields-attributes, attribute-joins, proximity

I am working on a project and the instruction I am given is:

> For each school, calculate an index of its exposure to toxic emissions. For all toxic sites within 1 mile of each school, divide the site’s toxic score by its distance to the school, then sum over the sites to create the index for the school. Hint: you could use the “Near” tool and then Join by FID.

I am working with a toxic sites point layer which has a toxic score field in the attribute table. I also have a schools point layer. Given these instructions I used the Near tool, inputting the toxic sites later and then the schools layer to get a near distance attribute in the toxic sites attribute field then I used calculate field to divide the toxic score by the near distance that I got from using the near tool. The part of these instructions I am unclear about is the "sum over the sites to create an index for the school". I have the calculated field in the toxic sites attribute table but I do not have it in the schools attribute table and I am unsure of how to join them. There do not seem to be any common fields between these two layers for me to join.

Comment: Near should give you a field called near_fid, that is the OID of the nearest school, you need to join your toxic sites to your school (toxic sites NEAR_FID to school FID/Objectid) then calculate field on the schools attributes ToxicExposure = ToxicExposure + ToxicScore, this will attribute the school with the sum of all toxic exposures. Be sure to cite GIS.SE when you hand in your homework.

Comment: Thank you so much for you help, that worked

Comment: I think that generate Near table IS correct tool for that.

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap?